# pip install mod_wsgi error

Tags: python, pip, mod-wsgi

I am getting the following error while trying to run the command `pip install mod_wsgi`.I have c++ installed already

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\mouni\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-lfndcw\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mouni\appdata\local\temp\pip-2si83h-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mouni\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-lfndcw\mod-wsgi\`
```

Can someone please help me in resolving it

Answer (score -2):

This error could be caused by an out of date version of pip. Try upgrading your version of pip by running the command:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

And then try installing mod_wsgi again.

Comment: I have updated the pip but still facing the same error

Comment: Updated the pip but still same error. I am using python 3.5 virtual environment.